# How are you supposed to remove the (1) next to the LaTeX equation?

Tags: equations

I'm new to LaTeX. I was writing this equation the other day.

```
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{1}^{n} =
   \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
       1, & n=1\\
       n+\sum_{1}^{n-1}, &\forall n>1
    \end{array}\right.
 \end{equation}
```

But when I executed it, there was always this `(1)` dangling on the side.

[image]

Can anyone help get rid of it?

Comment: JamesT has answered your question, but the idea of the (1) is that elsewhere in your paper you can say "as we saw/see in Equation (1)".  You can even use LaTeX's label/ref mechanism to have the (1) automatically change if you rearrange your equations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the starred environments to remove the automatic equation numbering i.e. `\begin{equation*`} and `\end{equation*}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
 \sum_{1}^{n} =
   \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
       1, & n=1\\
       n+\sum_{1}^{n-1}, &\forall n>1
    \end{array}\right.
 \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

---

A more succinct way that reduces typing is to follow the advice from @barbara beeton and use `\[` and `\]` to wrap the one-line equation in:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[
 \sum_{1}^{n} =
   \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
       1, & n=1\\
       n+\sum_{1}^{n-1}, &\forall n>1
    \end{array}\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

which produces the same output image.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Sean - The "starred" varieties of LaTeX commands and environments often [but not universally] serve to eliminate numbering. This is the case not only for `equation`/`equation*` display-math environments, but also for other, multi-line math environments -- `align` vs. `align*`, `gather` vs. `gather*`, etc -- and for commands such as `\chapter`, `\section`, and `\subsection`. To create unnumbered chapter, section, and subsection level headers, just write `\chapter*`, `\section*`, and `\subsection*`.

Comment: An alternative to `equation*` is to wrap the (one-line) display in `\[ ... \]`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `cases` enviroment.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{1}^{n} = \begin{cases}
       1, & n=1\\
       n+\sum_{1}^{n-1}, &\forall n>1
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In order to answer the question itself, you would need to use the starred `equation` environment ;)

Comment: @KersouMan Thank you very much for your advice.